# Merge or Append two Data models same structure to post values in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, post

Having the same structure of data models I want to merge data so I can post values to server on button click.

- Unit Model : I pass this model to AcceptanceViewcontroller in `var UnitData` for entering final
  remarks.
- Acceptance Model:  Only for Final remarks (comments) and
  few values.

How to merge both data into one swift.

```
var AppData : Acceptance?
var UnitData: Unit?
```

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(Acceptance.self, from: result! as! Data)
self.AppData = response
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Data Models:

```
struct Unit : Codable {

    var sectionList : [SectionList]?

}

struct Acceptance : Codable {

    var sectionList : [SectionList]?

}

struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?
}

struct Item : Codable {

    let actionType : Int?
    let actionUrl : String?
    let bgColor : String?
    let booleanValue : Bool?
    var textField : String?
    var textValue : String?
    let unitId : Int? 
    let latitude : Double?
    let longitude : Double?
    let actionParamData: String?
    let actionTitle: String?
    let pickList: [SectionList]?
    let multiSelect: Bool?
    let selectedValue: [String]?
    let version: Int?
    let masterId: Int?
    let itemValue: String?
}
```

Comment: you mean UnitData.sectionList.append(contentsOf: AppData.sectionList) ?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik yes or either way. because both have same structure. Actually I need all unit data values to be in App Data so club them and post to server.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik if I try like this way `UnitData.sectionList.append(contentsOf: AppData.sectionList)`  this gives me error `Value of type '[SectionList]?' has no member 'append'`

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik for this `UnitData?.sectionList?.append(AppData?.sectionList)` it gives me error of 
`Cannot convert value of type '[SectionList]?' to expected argument type 'SectionList' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, remember to name your variables starting with lower cases. `AppData` and `UnitData` should be renamed to `appData` and `unitData` respectively.

Anyway, the solution provided by @AlexandrKolesnik in the comments works. You should do:
`unitData?.sectionList?.append(contentsOf: appData?.sectionList ?? [])`

If you don't want `unitData` to be modified by adding `appData` to it, just make another array and append `unitData` and then `appData`.

```swift
var allSectionList: [SectionList] = []
allSectionList.append(contentsOf: unit?.sectionList ?? [])
allSectionList.append(contentsOf: acceptance?.sectionList ?? [])
```

---

To add the behavior described in the comments of this answer, I'd add a boolean variable to `SectionList` that indicates if it has been modified. And then whatever you want to merge both lists, only append those `SectionList` that have said variable as `true`. For example:

```swift
struct SectionList : Codable {
    let title : String?
    var items : [Item]?
    var modified = false
}
```

If your user modifies that `SectionList`, then set the `modified` variable as `true`. In the moment of merging the data:

```swift
var allSectionList: [SectionList] = []
allSectionList.append(contentsOf: unit?.sectionList ?? [])
acceptance?.sectionList?.forEach { section in
    if section.modified {
        allSectionList.append(section)
    }
}
```

You might need to set the `modified` variable to false once you've added it to the merged list, but that depends on you and if you need it.

Comment: Thank you. all perfect. 
Just for my information is it also possible I can append only updated/changed data Not all values.

Comment: Sure it is possible, you'd have to apply some logic to decide which are the updated/changed data values. I don't know how can you differentiate between old values and new/updated values, but I'm guessing you get the updated values from the `response`, so you can only append those values instead of the whole `appData` list.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am getting the updated values from `response` But in case of `Acceptance` I am updating only comment value and have to append it to `Unit` to post to server. How can I apply check logic which tableview cell is updated because for comment cell I am using delegate to get input from `textFieldViewController` and only this will be updated again n again. So it's not best practice to post all data.

Comment: To clarify, your users can write in your `Acceptance` cells textFields and then you want to somehow append only those cells that were modified by the user?

Comment: Pardon me Roberto disturbing you again. I have one question related to parameter thing, actually reference to this question I have to create body parameter string, I am doing and passing but not accurate. Implement different logic but same issue. Please can you guide me actually same model with other parameters. Here is link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190634/how-can-i-create-post-model-string-for-body-parameter-alamofire-swift